# How to save a point to Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, google-maps-markers

I'm looking for a solution that can allow me to save an address on the map map from latitude and longitude coordinates that I can use in my program directly. Example: When I generate the coordinates of a point that this ponit is automatically saved in google maps.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example?*

Comment: how to register an address in google maps with Api?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no available service in the Google Maps Platform for the function of registering new locations.

You can use the "Add a Missing Place" feature in https://www.google.com/maps for adding locations in the Map.

Steps :
https://www.google.com/maps > Menu > Add a Missing Place > Enter the required info

"Google My Business" also lets you register the service area of your business.